# How to set default values for multiple fields in a nested struct

Tags: go, struct, nested, default

Suppose you have the following:

```
type Animal struct {
    Name string
    Ears int
    Eyes int
}

type Dog struct {
    Animal `default:"Animal{Ears:'2', Eyes:'2'}"`
}
```

Is there a way to set the default? It doesn't work in the above.

1. `default:{Ears:'2', Eyes:'2'}`
2. `default.Ears:"2", default.Eyes:"2"}`

Comment: I'm curious where you got the idea that your `default:...` annotation would work.

Comment: I'm afraid not, but u can do some work around with struct method, to create an artificial constructor, similar to OOP, 

@KurtisRader some programming languages allow anotations similar to those in order to fill empty attributes, although not with that exact name, example: C#

Comment: @AndrewAlizaga, I realize that other languages support such mechanisms (I've been programming for more than four decades) but that doesn't explain how the O.P. got the idea that their example should work in Go.

Comment: @KurtisRader I read that default is how you assign a default to a value, but since it was a struct I was messing around different ways to set a default to a struct value

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're trying to use is not supported. You have to use a constructor function. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-assign-default-value-for-struct-field-in-golang/ for one decent discussion of that approach.

Comment: I am trying to create a custom marshal/unmarshalling for structs that all look the same but with different "default" values without repeating. So basically I need it to be a struct and not a function. I guess it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

In the code provided, the struct Dog embeds the Animal struct, and there seems to be an attempt to set default values for the Ears and Eyes fields of the embedded Animal struct. However, the syntax used is not valid for setting default values.

In Go, you cannot directly set default values for struct fields using tags like default:"...". Tags are used for other purposes like serialization, but they don't provide a mechanism for setting default values.

If you want to set default values for the fields of the embedded Animal struct in the Dog struct, you have a couple of options:

**1) Constructor function**:

You can create a constructor function for the Dog struct that initializes the embedded Animal struct with the default values you desire.

```
    type Animal struct {
            Name string
            Ears int
            Eyes int
        }
        
        type Dog struct {
            Animal
        }
        
        // NewDog creates a new Dog instance with default values for Animal fields.
        func NewDog(name string) *Dog {
            return &Dog{
                Animal: Animal{
                    Name: name,
                    Ears: 2,
                    Eyes: 2,
                },
            }
        }
```

**2) Initialize on declaration:**

You can simply set default values when declaring a new instance of the Dog struct.

```
        type Animal struct {
            Name string
            Ears int
            Eyes int
        }
        
        type Dog struct {
            Animal
        }
        
        func main() {
            myDog := Dog{
                Animal: Animal{
                    Ears: 2,
                    Eyes: 2,
                },
            }
            // You can set the name afterward if needed
            myDog.Name = "Buddy"
        }
```

Comment: If you want to achieve custom marshaling and unmarshaling behavior for structs without repeating the code for each struct, you can use embedded structs and implement the json.Marshaler and json.Unmarshaler interfaces for the embedded struct. This way, you can reuse the custom marshaling and unmarshaling logic across different structs. It would be helpful if you can provide more explanation what you had tried out?

Comment: The use case is that the JSON provides string values that translates to Boolean (e.g. "up" = true, "yes" = true). I can create a struct for each set, and the implement the json.Unmarshaler, but they will all look the same. The suggestion you provided above is exactly what I'm trying to do, with Animal being analogous to the embedded struct. But the outer structs need to have the values set for what is translated to True vs False so that during Unmarshalling, "yes" is not translated to True for a struct that requires "up". There's an alternative solution, just trying to see if this can work.